# While loop in linked list

Tags: javascript, loops

I don't understand why this loop actually loops through the linked list. I know this is a silly question. There is no increment of anything; it looks like it is going over the same element again and again.

```
current = head;
while(current.next) {current = current.next;}
current.next = node;
```

Comment: it works exactly as it says.... do you even know what a linked list is?

Comment: Each node in a linked list has a data element and a 'link' (next) pointing to the next item in the list. If the 'next' link is null (commonly used), you are at the end of the list. So, current node = head; means start at the beginning, and then while there is a node to move to (current.next [test ! false-y ]) current = current.next; advance to the next node. After the loop, you're at the end, so append the new node current.next = node;  node.next should be false-y like 0 or null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a basic idea of how LinkedLists work conceptually.

The actual node class isn't visible here but let's assume it looks something like this

`function Node (type) {
    this.next // points to next node in list
    // some more fields containing data
}`

so now, line by line:

`current = head`

this assigns the front most element of the list to the variable `current`

`while(current.next)`

this says to continue the while loop as long as the `next` field of `current` points to valid node.

`current = current.next`

I assume this is the line causing the most confusion. At the beginning `current` was the `head` node (the front most). The assignment `current = current.next` assigns the `next` field in `current` as equal to `current` itself. In this way, on every iteration of the `while` loop, `current` becomes its next node and the list is traversed (as long as a valid node is contained in `current`'s `next` field.

The key idea is that `current = current.next` keeps assigning the next node and hence the list is propagating.

Answer (score 0):

This works because the assignment operator changes `current` to the `next` property of what it previously was:

```
             ┌──────────┐             ┌──────────┐
             │          │   next      │          │   next
             │      *───┼──────────> │      *───┼─────────>
             │          │             │          │
             └──────────┘             └──────────┘
                  ↑
current ─────────┘
```

When executing the statement `current = current->next` then `current` will reference what `current->next` referenced before the assignment:

```
             ┌──────────┐             ┌──────────┐
             │          │   next      │          │   next
             │      *───┼──────────> │      *───┼─────────>
             │          │   ┌──────> │          │
             └──────────┘   │         └──────────┘
                             │
current ───────────────────┘
```

At the next iteration, `current` is thus no longer the same as in the previous iteration, and its `next` property refers to the next object in the list. After the assignment of that `next` property to `current`, it looks like this:

```
             ┌──────────┐             ┌──────────┐
             │          │   next      │          │   next
             │      *───┼──────────> │      *───┼─────────>
             │          │             │          │    ┌────>
             └──────────┘             └──────────┘    │
                                                         │
current ────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I read it as:

So long as `current` has a `.next` value, set current to that value.

When `current` no longer has a `.next` value – create and set new `.next` value from given `node`.